# How to use CSS and HTML tags to put a text follows a centered picture?

Tags: html, css

We try to place a horizontally centered image in the middle of a web page and place some words on the right side of the image.

```
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│               <Picture> <Words>      │
│                                      │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
```

The HTML is as follows currently:

```
<div class="mid1"><img src="img/pic1.jpg"></div>
<div class="mid2">Hello, how are u</div>
```

How to place text on the right side of a horizontally centered image by using CSS?

Comment: Please share with us your code.

Comment: how do you want in the middle : horizontally or vertically

Comment: Nice ASCII art :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3c4yjxpz/

Comment: Hi @RAN, I want to put the picture in the middle first, then the words behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/11h8gn8s/

This is also works:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
   <div class="text">
    <p>
     Words
    </p>
   </div>
 </div>


.wrapper {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `flex` to divide the screen

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="side">
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="side">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.row .middle img {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.row .side {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.row .middle {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5616jc2k/)

note that `flex: 1 0 auto;` means that the cell will grow as needed but not shrink, `flex: 0 1 auto;` the opposite. So the middle cell will be as wide as it's content and the sides will fill the rest

Comment: Is there other way useful without using flex?

Comment: @Jack You could do the same thing with a table

Comment: Hi @Dotan, could you give a sample? I wonder how to implement it. Thanks.